# Introductory book on Group Theory and Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I am an undergraduate student. I am looking for a best introductory Group Theory and Linear Algebra book. Please Suggest me some book.

Comment: one book on both?

Comment: No. Separate books

Comment: For Linear algebra you might like Axler

Comment: It is probably difficult to find an introductory book that contains both of the subjects. It requires some maturity to see the connections between linear algebra and group theory.

Comment: @Dhruv Rathore: I can recommend: "A Course in Group Theory" by John F. Humphreys, ISBN-10: 0198534590

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For group theory, you  may try Gallian's Contemporary abstract algebra. In this book the author splits group theory into $11$ chapters with good examples and exercises!

I also mention Gallian web [page](http://www.d.umn.edu/~jgallian/), it contains lot of sources for abstract algebra

For linear algebra, Friedberg and Axler are good choices !

Also [Axler web Page](http://linear.axler.net/) contains lot of videos explained by the author itself!

Answer (score 1):

I love the Linear Algebra book by Friedberg, Insel, and Spence.